# Unity: Cannot run a simple animation in ML Agent environment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

So I downloaded a simple asset of a chicken with its animation. If I create a new project and import the package and then move the prefab into the scene. The animation runs as it should when hitting the play button.

But this is where things get weird. If I move this asset inside a scene from ML-Agent, on hitting the play button, the agent moves (as it should) but not the chicken or any other animated character that I bring into the scene.

I also get a warning on animator when trying to run in the ML-Agent environment. The warning says

`The module which implements this component type has been force excluded in player settings. The object will be removed in play mode and from any builds you make`

Here is a screenshot attached as well, just in case if the explanation is not clear. In the screen shot you can see the agent moving while characters just standing and not moving.
[image]

I tried removing the package, reinstalling and re-importing everything but the warning persists, and the chicken or any other character do NOT animate.

If I go into the Player settings from Edit>Settings>Player Settings, I do not see any settings that needs to be changed.

Here is a screenshot of player settings

[image]

One of the solutions on the internet says to close the Unity project and delete the Library file from the project folder, and then restart Unity. But that does not seem to work as well

Comment: while ive seen this by the souinds of it you didnt look in the place it said that causes it, the player settings

Comment: updated the question with details of what I tried so far

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the error by installing 2D features from the Package Manager. The way I found that I needed this package was as follows:

I opened up the asset scene in a bran new unity project.
Opened the Package Manager and compared all the packages ( In Project, Built-in) that were installed.

Made sure that all the same packages are also installed for my ML-Agent scene. Once I installed 2D Features, it worked like a charm and the error went away.